# Aliasing Methods in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise for authentication, but I'm using two user models, Buyer and Seller.

By default, Devise will generate two methods such as current_buyer and current_seller.

I want to clean up my code and in a before_filter in my ApplicationController, I would like to alias the appropriate method to current_user.

What's the best way to do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with balexand that you should have one model for login and separate them by roles.

But it's up to you and there is the way to do it by using method:

```
def current_user
  current_seller || current_buyer
end
```

This would return `seller`, `buyer` or `nil`.

Comment: I'm starting to think this too. Integrating with OmniAuth is also proving to be a pain because it already assumes one model as far as I can tell and the workaround I have is kinda 'meh'. Right now I'm trying to use two subclasses of User to define default roles without having to resort to mass assignment.

Comment: Why don't just keep the seller and buyer but separate the login account out? So both seller and buyer has_one login_account and a login_account belongs_to a seller or a buyer (of course polymorphic).

Comment: I was initially trying to do something similar. Use devise for the authentication with a table called `users` but then have in my migration `t.references :actual_user, :polymorphic => true` Where the :actual_user is a Buyer or Seller object. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to scope it so that when I go to sellers/sign_up or buyers/sign_up, it knows what to set the :actual_user to.

Answer (score 1):

You might be making your design more complicated than necessary by having two user models. You may want to consider using one User model for authentication. Then you can have roles for Buyer and Seller if needed.

But if you really just want to alias a method in ApplicationController, you can just do this:

```
  private
  alias :current_user :current_seller
```

Or if you need something more dynamic you can just use a method.

Comment: I believe alias_method is preferable to alias, because alias_method allows you to change the alias later on.